# Strongloop loopback: Lock model instances atomically

Tags: loopbackjs

I am providing a REST Api via strongloop's loopback.

I need to add locking of model instances via some call like:

`POST /User/{id}/tryLock`

Which returns a Lock instance, with some additional information: Was the lock successful, which user locked the object, etc.

I am using the loopback-connector-mysql and I know that in synchronous MySQL I would use some form of:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
SELECT lockId FROM object WHERE id = objectId FOR UPDATE;

// This is C++ or Java or whatever:
if(lockId != NULL)
   Fatal("Object was locked")

INSERT INTO locks (objectId, userId, ...);
UPDATE object SET lockId = locks.lastInsertId WHERE id = objectId;
COMMIT;
```

Is something like this possible in loopback? I would love to implement this as a mixin, so that I can use it for selected models.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The thing to use would be [Remote Hooks](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks)

```
User.beforeRemote( "tryLock", function( ctx, modelInstance, next) {
   //put code here    
}
```

There is a way to execute SQL Statements through the loopback-connector-mysql.

So my gut feeling would be to see if you could write the SQL Statements into that (assuming your User  mode is bound to MySQL and the User model has been migrated into MySQL through Arc).

Here is an extract of the function available in the connector - you will have to do some research to find out how it's bound to the model to see if it's accessible.

```
MySQL.prototype.executeSQL = function(sql, params, options, callback) {
```

Comment: The problem is, that (when I understand that correctly) I cannot yet use transactions in loopback, due to its asynchronous nature.

Comment: I just saw this and will look into it: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/pull/99

Comment: Alternatively, you could break your transaction up into pieces, and then run one SQL command at a time - and evaluate the result in Javascript.